# Does it sound natural/acceptable: "He is flawed/wrong from head to toe"

Tags: phrase-usage

Does it sound natural: "He is flawed/wrong from head to toe"

I wonder how you can describe a person in whom you don't see any positive character traits. Does it sound natural or acceptable to say: He is flawed/wrong from head to toe ?

Answer (score 2):

"Flawed" and "wrong" do not mean the same. If you want to say a person is thoroughly without positive traits, "flawed" would work, but you should be careful about how you combine metaphors: because "flaw" often (and I think, basically) means "a physical defect or blemish, an imperfection", using it with "from head to toe" can suggest you are talking about physical appearance, not character. It might better to avoid the idiom ("his character is thoroughly flawed"), or use another adjective: "he is corrupt from head to toe".

"Wrong" means "incorrect" or "not what is desired". I can imagine someone saying, "I wouldn't pick him for the job – he's wrong from head to toe" – but this means only that he would not be good at that specific job, not that his character is in any way being questioned.

Comment: I don't think describing a person as flawed can ever really refer to physical blemishes. Even with ‘from head to toe’, I find it very strained to force myself to perceive it as being about physical, rather than moral/ethical, traits.

Comment: @Janus: I agree - it sounds like a clumsy/unnatural metaphoric usage to me too. If we're going to include some "spatial" element in a metaphoric reference to a moral attribute, I'd rather see something that doesn't directly involve the physical body: *He's dishonest **through and through***.